# Multiple-Add in a single View, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-views

I'm trying to add multiple items of the same type at once in a single View, while giving the model.

`@model List<Item>`

For the view, It renders, when I post back, the model is null, even though the form data is sent correctly but for some reason the mapping is not happening.

Comment: you need custom model binder - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complex items you need to index your collections for the model binder.

Change your loop to this which will be picked up by the model binder (without seeing your view or model I am using `Field` for demo purposes here).

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        .....
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i].Field)
        .....
    }
```

They will then be posted back to the server.

For more info on it see here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Thanks, I just need to also ask, What If I want at least one item in the collection to be filled without having the ModelState complain about the other required fields that weren't filled.

Comment: No probs, I've not had to do that before. You might have to add a flag to the model to say which item you want to remove the modelstate errors for. Then remove it on post. I would create another question as it is a good one to ask and someone else will have more info i'm sure. :)

Comment: What will happen if I want to insert more items than Model.Count ? -hutchonoid